# Can sleeping on the floor improve sleep quality?

Tags: sleep

I read many essays about ways to improve sleep quality. [One of these essays](http://www.capitalistconcept.com/post/15413178423/advantages-and-disadvantages-of-sleeping-on-the) was about the benefits of sleeping on the floor. At first I found it a ridiculous  idea that this would help me get deep sleep. However, I was convinced when I tried it myself.

Is there evidence that sleeping on the floor improves sleep quality?

Comment: Hello, could you please provide a link to the information you read about the benefits of sleeping the floor? Superficially, it sounds ridiculous (as you rightly point out!), but there may be something interesting there. Also, personal feelings about this would be off topic here, but we could address whether there have been scientifically collected data in support of this.

Comment: Thank you for your interest, I will provide the link in the Question above , and  I am waiting for your opinion after you read the provided essay in the link

Comment: I pointed out above that I have read a lot of essays concerning this important topic . However, i found the disadvantages of this idea scientifically can't be considered  a real evidence  ( as the link says ) : you will not be able to have a good night with your wife , you will get cold in winter ,  etc , to be honest , I haven't found a real evidence proves that this idea is ridiculous . In the other hand the advantages of this idea are really scientific : improved blood circulation , corrected posture , you will be protected from back and neck awful pain .

Comment: " In any case, in these last three years I have had no back or neck pain and my general health has been fantastic so I intend to continue ........sleeping blissfully on the floor! ☆*♥*☆ " [ a person who tried this way ]

Comment: The link is ( http://www.capitalistconcept.com/post/15413178423/advantages-and-disadvantages-of-sleeping-on-the )

Comment: I too realize sleeping in a floor feel so comfort.

Answer (score 1):

Sleeping on the floor could be comfortable for some people who does such, but when you sleep on bed usually and eventually decide to sleep on the floor, it'll seem impossible due to body adaptation.

It might take some weeks for such a person's body to adapt to sleeping on the floor. Let me use myself as a case study, I usually sleep on the bed, but a day arose when visitors came and I had to sleep on the floor, sincerely I found it hard to breathe because my ribs felt pressed against the floor.

So yes sleeping on the floor can improve sleep quality but on the other hand, it can't improve sleep quality.

Comment: Here on Health, we [*strongly encourage*](http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/q/1) using references. They are the only way in which we can tell if information is reliable or not. If you are struggling to find good sources, check out, [What are reliable sources?](http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/q/112) If you want to learn more about our site's stance on answers without references, check out, [Should answers without references be immediately deleted?](http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/q/283) Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Sleep quality is multi-factorial. It depends on several physical and mental factors which differ person to person. For instance patients with spinal problems are better to sleep in a supine position (sleep on the back) on a hard surface while allergic patients and children are better to sleep in a prone position (sleep on the stomach) because in this position mucosal secretions can run out easily and cause no breathing difficulty. So generally speaking, sleeping on the floor does not improve your sleep quality unless you have spinal or neck or muscular difficulties. For experiencing a good deep sleep it is suggested to have an early dinner, exercise daily, meditate before sleep and avoid caffeine and smocking.

Comment: Welcome to health SE :-). You gave some interesting information in your answer, but here reliable references are [strongly encouraged](http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/questions/1/should-we-require-references-to-back-up-all-answers) and answers without them risk being deleted, because the references are the only way for the community to verify an answer. You can always [edit] your answer to add some. Thanks!

Comment: at this moment I am not able to provide articles pdf file . I can provide the abstract links right now